# Parallel and parLapply - Error in checkForRemoteErrors: one node produced an error: attempt to apply an object that is not a function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Within an R Shiny application I'm trying to parallelise a part of the code that is exporting large Excel files.

I'm using the package `parallel` to parallelise my code and I use `openxlsx` to write Excel files.

I'm using R under Windows so I can only use the socket approach that is available through the function `parLapply`.

I installed all the necessary packages on each core and exported all the necessary variables to each core:

```
no_cores <- detectCores()
print(paste0("Configuring parallelisation (", no_cores, " cores) and setting up clusters"))
clust <- makeCluster(no_cores) # This line will take time
clusterEvalQ(clust, lapply(c("data.table", "shiny", "openxlsx"), library, character.only = TRUE))
clusterExport(clust, c("Template.IGTs_UniqueYEsGroups", "YE_Range", "Generate_Tabs4MassiveExport", "ContentsCellsStyle_HCentered"))
```

I also loaded a DLL and stored the R function that is based on this DLL on each core:

```
clusterEvalQ(clust, dyn.load(paste0("2._IGTs_-_Graph_routines_NoHash_C", .Platform$dynlib.ext)))
clusterEvalQ(clust, FindElementaryCircuits <- function(LocalLinks){return(.Call("FindElementaryCircuits", LocalLinks))})
```

After `parLapply`

```
parLapply(cl = clust, X = 1:nrow(TableMassiveExport4ShinySelection_Temp), fun = function(Row){
...
})
```

I closed the cluster: `stopCluster(clust)`.

My original code contains too many variables with too many dependencies and linked functions so it's not straightforward to write a minimal reproducible example here.

Every time I run my code, I got this error:

```
"Error in checkForRemoteErrors: one node produced an error: attempt to apply an object that is not a function"
```

It's a partial translation because I installed R in French and the last part of the original error message looks like this:

```
"Error in checkForRemoteErrors: one node produced an error: tentative d'appliquer un objet qui n'est pas une fonction"
```

Do you know what could be the typical reasons for this kind of error message?